# Trouble showing a union of sets is connected.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, path-connected

**Exercise.** Consider the open ball $S = \{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2: (x-1)^2 + y^2 < 1\}$ and the singleton $\{(0,0)\}$. Show that $S \cup \{(0,0)\}$ is connected.

**My attempt.** I know for a fact that $S$ is connected (just like any other open ball in $\Bbb R^2$) and that singletons are also connected. So initally I thought about using the fact that the union of connected sets is connected but obviously in this case we have that the intersection of the singleton and $S$ is empty and thus the result is not applicable. On the other hand, I also know that $S$ is path-connected (thus connected). What I thought after this was to define a continuous mapping from $[0,1]$ to the union we want and use the fact that the continuous image of a connected set is also connected, but I am having some trouble defining such function.

I can see graphically that this is indeed a connected set, but I want to show it algebrically!

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Two options that I can think about: the set $S \cup \{(0,0)\}$ is nested between $S$ and its closure $\overline{S}$, so it is connected. The second would use your idea about path connectedness. Make a path that connects $(0,0)$ to the center of $S$ $(1,0)$, then connectedness follows.

Comment: The union of S and (0,0) is the same as the union of S and the line segment connection (0,0) with (1,0). Now you have a union of two connected and intersecting sets.

Comment: @NicholasRobino Taking on your first idea, I came up with a doubt: Are subsets of a connected set also connected?

Comment: @Seabourn Not necessarily. Consider the subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that consists of the two sets $(0,1)$ and $(2,3)$.

Comment: @NicholasRobino Then what would be the justification for your first claim?

Comment: @Seabourn It is possible to show that if $A$ is a connected subspace of $X$, and if $A \subset B \subset \overline{A}$, then $B$ is also connected. I can write out a proof in the answers if you want, but it is a little bit long.

Comment: It's not needed @NicholasRobino . You stated it and I remembered it as soon as I read it! I've been taught that in class. Thanks for your time and patience.

Comment: @ Seabourn No problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your set is the union of two connected sets with non-empty intersection: $S$ and the line segment from $(0,0)$ to $(1,0)$. Therefore, it is connected.

Comment: Thanks! You mean just like what @blamocur commented right?

Comment: I did not read the comments. Yes, it's the same thing. Do you want me to delete my answer?

Comment: Obviously you can keep the answer! Thanks for the time and help!

Comment: Just one more thing if that's okay: Consider we have two open balls, the same $S$ and $T = \{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 : (x+1)^2+y^2 < 1\}$ and again we also have the singleton $\{(0,0)\}$. To show that $S \cup T \cup \{(0,0)\}$ is connected how would one proceed? Because I reckon the same procedure won't be valid (since $S \cup T$ is not connected).

Comment: Since $S\cup\{(0,0)\}$ and $T\cup\{(0,0)\}$ are connected and their intersection is non-empty, their union, which is $S\cup T\cup\{(0,0)\}$, is connected.

Comment: Each of those sets is path-connected, since, for each $p$ in them, the line segment from $(0,0)$ to $p$ is contained in the set.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted the comment because I think I figured a way (using a similar procedure than you showed for the other cases). I was thinking using the fact that $S \cup \overline{T} = [S \cup \{(0,0)\}] \cup \overline{T}$ which is, again, the union of two connected sets with non-empty intersection. Would this suffice?

Comment: Yes, that works too.